# Can't stop localhost:3000 redirecting to https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https

My localhost:3000 will not open with safari saying `Cannot open the page https://localhost:3000 because safari cannot establish a secure connection.`

This made me realise that the browser was redirecting from http to https.  This made some sense as I had very recently added `config.force_ssl = true` in my config/environments file. I had added this in both development and production environments it seems so I've removed it completely from development.  Stopped the rails server, and then restarted it. But it's still redirecting. Where else might this be coming from? I get the same result in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Clear your browser cache and check it again it will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearing the browser cache did indeed fix it.  I'll leave this question in case others have the same problem. Thanks @ashvin.

Comment: Welcome :), glad to know that your issue is fixed.

Comment: you saved me :D